# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHtml' of null. even after rearranging the code

Tags: javascript, html

the innerHtml property is not working --Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHtml' of null

well i have rearranged the code..so that the dom gets loaded first ,still the error persist

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>playing till <span id="qwe"></span></h3><br>
<input type="number"><button class="q1">play limit</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="java_script"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

******java_script file******

```
document.querySelector(".q1").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("qwe").innerHTML=" limit" ;
});
```

Comment: `innerHTML` not "innerHtml" - voting to close as typo

Comment: made the mentioned changes error still persist

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: Are you able to turn the posted code into a snippet that reproduces the error? When I tried it worked as intended -  possibly something not shown in the post is at fault.

Comment: Where do you import this JS file? If it's at the top, then the error occurs because when the JS file loads, the `"qwe"` element hasn't rendered yet—if so, move the import to the bottom of the file.

Comment: thanks ..its working now..

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by benvc in comment, your problem is simply with the syntax of your code.

The "HTML" part of innerHTML should be uppercase. This line should work.

```
document.getElementById("qwe").innerHTML =" limit" ;
```

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that language keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters.

See this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) for another example.

Note, however, that HTML is not case-sensitive.